# Как переслать команду от браузера desktop приложению?

Tags: веб-программирование

У пользователя на компе есть работающее desktop-приложение windows и есть сайт открытый в браузере. Как отправить команду с сайта(браузера) этому приложению?

PS. Это нужно для следующего сценария:
Пользователь регистрируясь через приложение должен подтвердить почту, для того чтобы упростить я сразу же после регистрации открываю окно куда нужно ввести код с почты. В письме же присутствует возможность просто перейти по ссылке и таким образом тоже подтвердить почту. В этот момент я бы хотел закрыть лишнее окно в приложении, для того чтобы дать понять пользователю что теперь можно вводить логин и пароль, а не код.

Comment: Браузер передаёт на серверную часть сайта сообщение. Потом сайт (сервер) должен общаться с десктопным приложение. Как это общение можно организовать зависит от языка программирования. Напишите какой у вас серверный язык. Так же хочу добавить что это очень редкий сценарий работы. Возможно вам необходимо пересмотреть что вам именно действительно нужно. Может быть в вопросе, опишите саму задачу?

Comment: Всё можно сделать гораздо проще. Так, как это делает стим или скайп - при установке программа должна зарегистрировать в системе протокол, по которому браузер к ней сможет обратиться (`skype://makecoffee`). Как точно это делается, я, увы, не знаю. Погуглите.

Comment: Вот тут есть инструкция: http://kb.mozillazine.org/Register_protocol

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин, да, такой способ я мог бы сделать, но это действительно редкий способ, меня больше интересовал способ описанный в комменте ниже

Comment: @BeastWinterwolf как думаете способ, описанный по вашей ссылке, будет работать для хрома?

Comment: @ИванК протокол регистрируется в системе, не в браузере, по этому один метод должен работать для всех браузеров. Проблема может быть только с разными операционными системами.

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин отредактировал вопрос, чтобы было более понятно зачем мне это нужно.

Comment: @BeastWinterwolf сделал как вы говорили, теперь есть проблема как вызвать эту ссылку так чтобы браузер не ругнулся, например через js? Пробую не получается пишет:  "Не удалось найти в семействе маршрутов маршрут с именем"

Comment: @ИванК Я не специалист по протоколам. Если бы я всё досконально знал, то оформил бы полноценный ответ :<